# Explicitly fields aren't returned in serializer in django-rest-framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get a serializer of a model with a field from another model which are related by a foreign key relation. The desired result should be:

```
"coordinates": [
        {
            "coordinate": "42.0677",
            "coordinate_type": "shooting_latitude"
        },
        {
            "coordinate": "-8.0990",
            "coordinate_type": "shooting_longitude"
        }
]
```

And the models are:

```
class CoordinatesType(models.Model):
    coordinate_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    coordinate_description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)

class Coordinates(models.Model):
    coordinate_type = models.ForeignKey('hauls.CoordinatesType', null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coordinate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4, null=False, blank=False)
```

I can do it with a nested serializer:

```
class CoordinatesTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CoordinatesType
        fields = ['coordinate_type']

class CoordinatesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    coordinate_type = CoordinatesTypeSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Coordinates
        fields = ['coordinate', 'coordinate_type', ]
```

In this case, the result of the serializer is:

```
"coordinates": [
        {
            "coordinate": "42.0677",
            "coordinate_type": {
                "coordinate_type": "shooting_latitude"
            }
        },
        {
            "coordinate": "-8.0990",
            "coordinate_type": {
                "coordinate_type": "shooting_longitude"
            }
        }
]
```

And then I could override the to_representation() method to avoid the nesting data and get the desired result. But, in this case with only one nested field, I think it could be simpler create an explicit field and I tried:

```
class CoordinatesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    coordinate_type = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="coordinatestype.coordinate_type")

    class Meta:
        model = Coordinates
        fields = ['coordinate', 'coordinate_type', ]
```

But looks like the serializer ignore the explicit field returning this:

```
"coordinates": [
        {
            "coordinate": "42.0677"
        },
        {
            "coordinate": "-8.0990"
        }
]
```

Why is the reason of this result? I think there is something that I'm missing.

Comment: I believe that `source="coordinate_type.coordinate_type"` in your serializer field should solve it ?

Comment: Thanks, it works... but I don't understand why the first 'coordinate_type' is 'coordinate_type', instead of  'coordinatestype'.

Comment: I gave a more detailed answer, if you don't mind validating it. Don't hesitate if that's not enough explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment, the answer is:

```
class CoordinatesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    coordinate_type = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="coordinate_type.coordinate_type")

    class Meta:
        model = Coordinates
        fields = ['coordinate', 'coordinate_type', ]
```

Explanation:

Your serializer model is CoordinatesType and the foreign key relationship is represented by the field `coordinate_type` on the other model, Coordinates. This is a reverse relationship you're trying to do.

Alternatively, if you wanted to keep `source="coordinatestype.coordinate_type"` in your serializer you would need to change the [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) argument in your Model as follow:

```py
class Coordinates(models.Model):
    coordinate_type = models.ForeignKey('hauls.CoordinatesType', 
                                        null=False, blank=False, 
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                        related_name='coordinatestype')
```

Hope that gave you additional explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Django queries across relational fields differently.

`source = "coordinate_type__coordinate_type"` should work in your case.

Note the double `_` between the field name and the field name of the related model